# MVC4 aspx view engine how to insert <br> in error message

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in MVC4 Aspx view engine.
In validation method I am returning error message which I want to display in multiple lines. I have tried to put line break in the following ways but it always display it as  characters and not as a line break.

I have tried to concatenated 
  < br >
   \r\n 
      <br>

Here is my code example:

```
    ErrorMessage = "Your password has not been updated. Passwords must contain:" + "&lt;br&gt;" +
                           "at least 8 characters<br/>" +
                           "one lower case and at least one upper case character" + "\r\n" +
                           "at least one number\r\n" +
                           "at least one non-alphanumeric (e.g. ! @ # $)\r\n" +
                           "no parts of the username longer than 2 characters";
```

Please guide what I m missing.

Comment: What code are you using to output the ErrorMessage to the view?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your view:

```
<%= Html.Raw(ErrorMessage) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**ASP.net** engine :

```
<%= Html.Raw(ErrorMessage) %>
```

**Razor** engine :

```
@Html.Raw(Erroressage)
```